# I would like to ask if there's a way to shorten this ternary statement?

Tags: javascript, ternary

I would like to know the possibilities on how to shorten ternary statement here? TIA

```
data_items.attributes.promo_banner.promo_join_button_style === 'primary-flat' ? 'primary-flat' : data_items.attributes.promo_banner.promo_join_button_style === 'secondary-flat' ? 'secondary-flat' : data_items.attributes.promo_banner.promo_join_button_style === 'tertiary-flat' ? 'tertiary-flat' : data_items.attributes.promo_banner.promo_join_button_style === 'primary-animated' ? 'primary-animated' : data_items.attributes.promo_banner.promo_join_button_style === 'secondary-animated' ? 'secondary-animated' : data_items.attributes.promo_banner.promo_join_button_style === 'tertiary-animated' ? 'tertiary-animated' : 'error' "
```

Comment: Variables, use variables to store a mile long reference.

Comment: Create an array or Set of possible values. Check if that *includes* the button_style value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const dataStyle = data_items.attributes.promo_banner.promo_join_button_style;

dataStyle === "primary-flat"
  ? "primary-flat"
  : dataStyle === "secondary-flat"
  ? "secondary-flat"
  : dataStyle === "tertiary-flat"
  ? "tertiary-flat"
  : dataStyle === "primary-animated"
  ? "primary-animated"
  : dataStyle === "secondary-animated"
  ? "secondary-animated"
  : dataStyle === "tertiary-animated"
  ? "tertiary-animated"
  : "error";
```

---

Btw you should not use such long ternary operators. For such code try using a switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

For readability use a shorter variable name to store the value. Then, since you are returning the input value when it matches one of the styles, you can put the styles into an array, and then you can use `Array.includes` to test them all at once:

```js
button_styles = ['primary-flat', 'secondary-flat', 'tertiary-flat', 'primary-animated', 'secondary-animated', 'tertiary-animated' ];

promo_button_style = data_items.attributes.promo_banner.promo_join_button_style;

button_styles.includes(promo_button_style) ? promo_button_style : 'error'
```

Note that for large arrays a `Set` (with [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)) would be more efficient:

```js
button_styles = new Set(['primary-flat', 'secondary-flat', ...])

button_styles.has(promo_button_style) ? promo_button_style : 'error'
```